# How to use file imported from tkinter in rest of Python code

Tags: filedialog

I'm trying to import a file from a tkinter GUI to be used in the rest of my code.

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def FileImport():
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    label = tk.Label(root, text = "Selected: "+file).pack()

root= tk.Tk() 
root.title('Main')
label = tk.Label(root, text = "Upload a file: ", fg="purple").pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text='Upload',fg="blue", command=FileImport)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()

uploaded_file = np.fromfile(file)
```

Then I'm trying to perform calculation and other things on that file data.

The issue is that when I run the code the GUI works "fine", I am able to upload a file but then it tells me that name 'uploaded_file' is not defined. I think I'm missing some connection between my GUI and the rest of my code? Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `file=''` and then calling it in function with global can solve this problem.
Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
file = ''

def FileImport():
    global file
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    label = tk.Label(root, text = "Selected: "+file).pack()

root= tk.Tk()
root.title('Main')
label = tk.Label(root, text = "Upload a file: ", fg="purple").pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text='Upload',fg="blue", command=FileImport)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
uploaded_file = np.fromfile(file)
print(uploaded_file)
```

Hope It helps!

Comment: Thank you but it didn't change anything.  Going to try reading more about it!

Comment: Is it giving the same error as you have described above??

Comment: Actually my bad. It does work! I was testing this in my main code and there is so much going on something else might be derailing it. Tested it in a separate file and it does work! Thanks a lot! :)